# Apply cellfun to only one column in cell array

Tags: matlab

I know cellfun can be applied to an entire cell array and understand its syntax. However is it possible to apply cellfun only to one column in a cell array and not have it affect the other columns?

Comment: If your cell array is called `C` and you only wanted to apply to column `i`, can you just do cellfun('function', C{:, i})?

Comment: As a correction you would do `cellfun(@foo, C(:,i))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As user1543042 and It's magic said in the comments, you can apply the cell function to just one column using ':', but you want to add an assignment step.  Also, as you want the cell function to return a cell array, you need to flag non-uniformoutput.  So, you end up with:

```
C(:,i) = cellfun(@foo, C(:,i), 'UniformOutput', false)
```

To see an example in action:

```
>> C = {1,2,3;4 5 6};
>> C
C = 
    [1]    [2]    [3]
    [4]    [5]    [6]
>> size(C)
ans =
     2     3
>> cellfun(@(x)x.^2,C(:,1))
ans =
     1
    16
>> C(:,1) = cellfun(@(x)x.^2,C(:,1))
Conversion to cell from double is not possible. 
>> C(:,1) = cellfun(@(x)x.^2,C(:,1),'UniformOutput',false)
C = 
    [ 1]    [2]    [3]
    [16]    [5]    [6]
>>
```

Comment: Perfect. This will come in handy. Thanks.